# How can an admin (coach) create a new user (athlete) through firebase cloud functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a web app for coaches and athletes. In the app, coaches should be able to add athletes to the app. These athletes should then receive an email with a login link and the athlete should be added to a user collection in the firestore database.

I've created the following cloud function that checks if the user is a coach and then makes a new user.

```js
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth?.token.coach) return "You are not a coach!";

  return admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: data.email,
      emailVerified: true,
      password: data.password,
      displayName: data.firstname,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      console.log("Successfully crated new user:", userRecord.uid);
      return userRecord.uid;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      return "An error has occured";
    });
});
```

Then I call the cloud function in this section.

```js
const functions = getFunctions();
const addGymnasts = httpsCallable(functions, "createUser");

 const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ref = collection(db, "Gymnasts", user.uid, "Gymnasts");

    await addDoc(ref, {
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    await addGymnasts({ email: "", firstname: "", password: ""});
    setFirstname("");
    setLastname("");
  };
```

The new user is getting stored in the firestore database in the right collection, and the cloud function it self runs, but the new created user is not added to the Users in Authentication. What is not correct?

Comment: Consider using `GymnastsByCoach/{coachUserId}/Gymnasts` instead of `Gymnasts/{coachUserId}/Gymnasts`. By naming them differently, this will save problems later if you want to use Collection Group Queries. Also consider changing `uid` to `coachId` or `coachUid` to disambiguate them.

Comment: It's unclear how your app behaves once `setFirstname` and `setLastname` are called, but it is possible that all you are missing is the `await` before the `addGymnasts()` call.

Comment: In addition to Sam's points, you're not passing any information to `addGymnasts();`, so the `data` object in your Cloud Function will be empty.

Comment: I've added the await and now the function is at least running in the logs. But a new user still isn't added. What data object do I need to pass to addGymnasts(). I've tried data and email.data, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const functions = getFunctions();
const addGymnasts = httpsCallable(functions, "createUser");

 const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ref = collection(db, "Gymnasts", user.uid, "Gymnasts");

    await addDoc(ref, {
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    addGymnasts(); // Here i've put the cloud function 
    setFirstname("");
    setLastname("");
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).